# What's the difference between a melee and a custom match in StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

For clarification, I know that you pick custom when you want special maps like Sotis or TD maps, and melee if you want good ol' RTS style. But why do we have to select "custom game" to earn achievements? why not melee?

Comment: Are you asking why Blizzard decided to make their achievement only earn on certain maps and not others? or are you asking which maps you can earn certain achievements on?

Comment: im asking the difference between a melee Blistering sands map against an ai vs a custom Blistering sands map against an ai. I tried melee before and didnt get any progress on any achievement, but when i switched it to custom i got progress. is there a difference between a melee and custom map(if there are no modifications) at all?

Comment: I guess I thought melee was just a mode for a map where custom was mode for the type of game, no?

Comment: I sometimes forget to set the game to Custom so when I continue with a melee game, it feels kind of a waste of time since winning it won't add to the 'Protoss AI romp' achievement for example.

Comment: Are you sure about what you are saying?  I'm pretty sure you only get achievements in Melee and not in Customs.  Because in Customs you can change the rules of the game... you could add infinite money for instance and get all achievements really easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is confusing because there are two definitions for **Custom** in StarCraft II.  There is the overarching **Custom Game** type which can have a **Custom** category or a **Melee** category.

**Custom Game** encompasses all games which are *not* one of the following:

- Ladder game
- Cooperative game
- Free-for-all
- Single player campaign

You need to select **Custom Game** and the **Melee** category to earn achievements under the Custom Game achievement section.  The reason for this is **Melee** category games always have the same conditions for victory--*destroy all opponent buildings*--whereas **Custom** category games can have any number of victory conditions, such as *destroying the Nexus* in Nexus Wars or *defeating all waves of creeps* in a Tower Defense game.